# Infinite recursion in SWI-Prolog

Tags: recursion, prolog, family-tree

I am trying to define a family tree and the relationships between its nodes basing their definitions on three predicates: `male/1`, `female/1` and `parent_of/2`.

I have defined the notions of ascendant, descendant, father, mother, son, daughter, grandfather, grandmother, aunt, uncle and cousin. Any new definition can't be based on the notion of "brother/sister of", but only on the previous ones.

This is the code:

```
male(daniel).
male(miguelangel).
male(mario).
male(mahmoud).
male(esteban).
male(enrique).
male(javier).
male(miguelin).

female(diana).
female(hengameh).
female(vicenta).
female(mahvash).
female(angeles).
female(mexicana).
female(eloina).
female(esmeralda).
female(cristina).
female(otilia).

parent_of(miguelangel, daniel).
parent_of(miguelangel, diana).
parent_of(hengameh, daniel).
parent_of(hengameh, diana).
parent_of(mario, miguelangel).
parent_of(mario, esteban).
parent_of(mario, eloina).
parent_of(mario, angeles).
parent_of(mario, otilia).
parent_of(vicenta, miguel).
parent_of(vicenta, esteban).
parent_of(vicenta, eloina).
parent_of(vicenta, angeles).
parent_of(vicenta, otilia).
parent_of(mahmoud, hengameh).
parent_of(mahvash, hengameh).
parent_of(enrique, javier).
parent_of(angeles, javier).
parent_of(cristina, miguelin).
parent_of(otilia, cristina).
parent_of(eloina, esmeralda).

% Rules

ancestor(X, Y) :-
    parent_of(X, Y);
    parent_of(X, Z),
    ancestor(Z, Y).

descendant(X, Y) :-
    ancestor(Y, X).

father(X, Y) :- 
    parent_of(X, Y),
    male(X).

mother(X, Y) :-
    parent_of(X, Y),
    female(X).

son(X, Y) :-
    parent_of(Y, X),
    male(X).

daughter(X, Y) :-
    parent_of(Y, X),
    female(X).

grandfather(X, Y) :-
    parent_of(X, Z),
    parent_of(Z, Y),
    male(X).

grandmother(X, Y) :-
    parent_of(X, Z),
    parent_of(Z, Y),
    female(X).

aunt(X, Y) :-
    (grandfather(Z, Y) ; grandmother(Z, Y)),
    (father(Z, X) ; mother(Z, X)),
    not(parent_of(X, Y)),
    female(X).

uncle(X, Y) :-
    (grandfather(Z, Y) ; grandmother(Z, Y)),
    (father(Z, X) ; mother(Z, X)),
    not(parent_of(X, Y)),
    male(X).

cousin(X, Y) :-
    ((uncle(Z, Y), parent_of(Z, X)) ; (cousin(P, Y), descendant(X, P)));    
    ((aunt(Z, Y), parent_of(Z, X)) ; (cousin(P, Y), descendant(X, P))).
```

For the sake of clarity I have represented through an image the part of the tree where I'm having issues:

[image]

When I write

```
cousin(X, Y) :-
    ((uncle(Z, Y), parent_of(Z, X)));   
    ((aunt(Z, Y), parent_of(Z, X))).
```

instead of

```
cousin(X, Y) :-
    ((uncle(Z, Y), parent_of(Z, X)) ; (cousin(P, Y), descendant(X, P)));    
    ((aunt(Z, Y), parent_of(Z, X)) ; (cousin(P, Y), descendant(X, P))).
```

I get

```
?- cousin(miguelin, daniel).
false.

?- cousin(cristina, daniel).
true .
```

which are valid results. But when I introduce the recursive definitions on the right, as stated on the first (big) code, for saying that the descendants of the cousins of Y are also the cousins of Y, the program crashes:

```
?- cousin(miguelin, daniel).
ERROR: Out of local stack
```

I don't understand why. If I look at the image, it makes sense (at least to me) that recursive definition, and `miguelin` should be now the cousin of `daniel` (since he is a descendant of another cousin of `daniel`, which is `cristina`). I also tested it "manually" and I got the right result:

```
?- cousin(cristina, daniel), descendant(X, cristina).
X = miguelin ;
```

What's wrong with the definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem with the `cousin/2` predicate is that the recursion is occurring before you resolve the `descendant/2`, and `cousin/2` is having an infinite recursion issue in this context. As a simple way to fix that, you can swap them around. Also, you have one redundant recursive subclause. So the modified `cousin/2` predicate would be:

```
cousin(X, Y) :-
    (uncle(Z,Y), parent_of(Z,X)) ;
    (aunt(W,Y), parent_of(W,X)) ;
    (descendant(X,P), cousin(P,Y)).
```

And then you get:

```
?- cousin(miguelin, daniel).
true ;
false.

?- cousin(cristina, daniel).
true ;
false.

?-
```

Comment: Oh, I see. I forgot that, although in logic the order of two predicates joined by a conjunction doesn't matter, in Prolog does matter because of the nature of the machine on which it is running. Thank you for helping me out :)

Comment: @DanielMuñozParsapoormoghadam technically you're correct: logically, the predicate should work as-is. However, there's a circular logic issue with `cousin` which I side-stepped by considering the `descendant` first, thereby narrowing the options for `cousin`. It also made the predicate tail recursive. With some other rewrites, it would be possible to makes the query to `cousin` first work properly. But what I showed was the easiest approach. I reworded my answer to reflect that.